# C++ - calling a base class' overridden virtual method from inside base class' operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a base class, that I'll call `Base`, and a derived class `Derived`. `Base` class has a method called `readInData(istream)`, which is called from inside a defined `operator>>` function. `Derived` has it's own definition of `readInData(istream)`, but does not yet have it's own definition for the operator (inherits the definition from `Base`.

My question is, if `Derived`, uses the operator defined in base, that calls the method defined in both classes, will it be `Base::readInData(istream)` or `Derived::readInData(istream)` that gets called?

I would like `Derived::readInData(istream)` to be called, so will I need to also redefine the operator to do this?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question states that the function is virtual, it will be Derived::readInData(istream) that is called.

Comment: Phenomenal news. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
{
public:
  void print()
  {
    std::cout << saySomething() << std::endl;
  }
  virtual std::string saySomething()
  {
    return "hey!";
  }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  virtual std::string saySomething()
  {
    return "I am B!";
  }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  system("pause");

  B b;
  b.print();

  system("pause");
}
```

Output: I am B!